# Euler-Lagrange equation minimal surface/graph

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

> Let $u:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable, $$\cal{F}(u):=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+u'(t)^2}dt.$$ Find $u$ with $u(a)=u_0, u(b)=u_1$.

Idea: Minimalizing. It is $0=\frac{d}{ds}\cal{F}(u+s\phi)|_{s=0}=\int_a^b\frac{u'(t)\cdot \phi(t)}{\sqrt{1+u'(t)^2}}$, so integration by parts and the fundamental lemma gives $$\left(\frac{u'(t)}{\sqrt{1+u'(t)^2}}\right)'=0$$ Now I need to find $u$ which satisfies the initial conditions.  It is $\frac{u'(t)}{\sqrt{1+u'(t)^2}}$ constant so I thought $$\frac{u'(t)}{\sqrt{1+u'(t)^2}} \equiv c \Rightarrow u'(t)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{1+c^2}}$$ Integrating gives $$u(t)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{1+c^2}}\cdot t+c_0$$ with $u(a)=\frac{ac}{\sqrt{1+c^2}}+c_0=u_0$ and $u(b)=\frac{bc}{\sqrt{1+c^2}}+c_0=u_1$ to find $c$ and $c_0$. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line does not make sense. Why do you still have $t$ in thjose equations? And why does $c_0$ appear twice?

You can simplify your equations byreplacing $\frac c{\sqrt{1+c^2}}$ by some new constant $d$.
Then $$u(t)=d\cdot t+c_0$$so
$$u(a)=d\cdot a+c_0=u_0\\u(b)=d\cdot b+c_0=u_1$$
Subtracting these two equations you get $$d(a-b)=u_0-u_1$$ or $$d=\frac{u_1-u_0}{b-a}$$
and then use either of those equations to find $c_0$.

Comment: Okay thank you! I made an edit in the last line. Does the idea/ansatz make sense?

Comment: Yes. But use the simplified form for the constant. It will make the calculations easy. If you look at the interpretation of the problem, you are asked about a curve in the plane, connecting $(a, u_0)$ to $(b,u_1)$, that has the minimum length. This is the straight line between those points.